# ActiveRecord query to list all items in order starting with the selected object in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a list of Videos that belongs_to a category. When someone goes to the show action of a video I want that video to be first in the list then list all the other videos belonging to the same category to be listed ordered by **name**.

I've been thinking of ways to best describe this problem and came to the conclusion it's better to visually explain what I'm trying to achieve. Say every video has an ID from 1-6 (remove ordering for the sake of simplicity). **If ID params is 4 I want the following order to apply: 4-5-6-1-2-3**

In other words, the list needs to wrap around until all videos have been listed. Number of videos may change but it is possible to do a count on number of videos before the query.

Comment: Does the order have to resume from the selected video? Can it be 4-1-2-3-5-6?

Comment: Yes, it needs to resume from the selected video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you will have to use a few `where` queries. Let's take `@selectedvideo` as the video that has been selected by the user.

Then:

```
@highervids = Video.where(
  'category = ? AND id > ?',
  @selectedvideo.category, @selectedvideo.id
).order("id DESC")

@lowervids = Video.where(
  'category = ? AND id < ?',
  @selectedvideo.category, @selectedvideo.id
).order("id DESC")
```

So now basically all of the videos before the selected video are in `@lowervids` and the videos after are in `@highervids`, and they're all in descending order. You can now simply render them.

Comment: I think order should be "id" instead of "id DESC"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be pretty much easy:

In your controller:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@similar_videos = @video.category.videos
```

In your views:

```
= render @video
= render @similar_videos - @video
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, it needs to start from the selected Video then continue based on a field in the Video model (title/position etc.) until there is no higher value. Then go back to the beginning up until current video. Hope that explains in more detail.